# How to determine which combination of orders would be optimal, in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, math

I am struggling with a small task in Excel. I have two options to choose from when ordering in bulk. Option A - 5 pieces for 80$. Option B - 30 pieces for 200$. I cannot buy single pieces and I have to buy in bulk. How can I write a formula that can check which combination of the bulk orders I should make? For example, if I want to order 34 pieces, then it would be better to order Option B once and Option A once, instead of ordering Option B twice or Option A 7 times.

I tried to find an equation, where the x-intercept would show how many Option A's to order but it only works in very simplistic cases and not for all possible inputs. I think that the answer to this might lie in an IF formula but I am not sure.

Comment: I think this question belongs to another site, like https://math.stackexchange.com/ because you are looking for an equation. Once you got that, then maybe you can ask how to make a formula for that equation

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Wouldn't it also belong here since I presume you could write a formula for this using nested if loops?

Comment: To write a formula, you need to know the *manual formula*, how to resolve it. You need the equation itself. Translating that equation into Excel is, indeed, a question for SO (showing some minimal effort). But getting the equation I think is out of the scope. Anyways, I did not vote to close the question, is just my opinion :)  Maybe other users can light us up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem for integer linear programming:

```
Parameters:
    n  =  34 = wanted number of pieces
    pA =  80 = price of A 
    pB = 200 = price of B
    nA =   5 = number of pieces per A
    nB =  30 = number of pieces per B

Decision variables:
    qA, qB = number of lots A, number of lots B, integers

Minimize:
    pA * qA + pB * qB

Under constraints:
    nA * qA + nB * qB >= n
    qA >= 0
    qB >= 0
```

On the other hand, the problem is simple enough, because the price per piece is much cheaper for B (pB/nB = 6.67) than for A (pA/nA = 16); and the price of one B is between the price of 2 and 3 A. So, there is an obvious heuristic: divide the wanted number of pieces by 30 to pick as many B as you can, pick one additional B if there is more than 2 A left, otherwise complete with A.

```
qB = floor(n / 30)
if n - 30 * qB > 2:
  qB += 1
  qA = 0
else:
  qA = ceil((n - 30 * qB) / 5)
```